# How do I install Fish Shell on AWS Linux

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-web-services, fish

I can't seem to install Fish shell on an AWS Linux instance. I keep getting the following error and can't seem to find a fix for it.

```
[root@ip-172-31-20-125 ec2-user]# yum -y install fish
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Repository shells_fish_release_2 is listed more than once in the configuration
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package fish.x86_64 0:2.5.0-1.2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: hostname for package: fish-2.5.0-1.2.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: fish-2.5.0-1.2.x86_64 (shells_fish_release_2)
           Requires: hostname
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: I've also tried the RPM package with the same results as above, it's complaining about requiring the hostname.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Same way as on Centos 6.

[from:](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=shells%3Afish%3Arelease%3A2&package=fish)

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/shells:fish:release:2/CentOS_6/shells:fish:release:2.repo
yum install fish
```

---

2021 update:

If you're running a newer version of AWS Linux - run `rpm -E %{rhel}` to see the RHEL version, and then use [one of the links here](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=shells%3Afish%3Arelease%3A3&package=fish) for the `wget` command. For instance, if the RHEL version is 7, run as root:

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/shells:fish:release:3/CentOS_7/shells:fish:release:3.repo
yum install fish
```

Comment: I still get the same error. I've run yum update too for good measure.

Comment: try also yum install net-tools, that one provides hostname

Comment: Hostname is its own package on centos 7. For aws linux need centos 6 repo, maybe you accidently installed the one for 7.

Comment: I tried both 7 and 6. I knew how to get the hostname, but do I need to put that in the yum command for Fish to install properly? I'm not quite sure what it wants, hostname is easy, but where do I put it?

Comment: The error "shells_fish_release_2 is listed more than once" sounds like you still have the repos.d file for 7. Try delete /etc/yum.repos.d/shells:fish* and then the commands just for centos 6 again

Comment: I deleted both, ran the wget for 6, ran the install and got the same error.

Comment: You need to run `yum clean all` after changing the repos.d file.

Comment: The CentOS 7 package worked for me on the AWS Linux **2** image.

Comment: Running `yum clean all` and retrying fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Fish's Red Hat 6 package repository, which works out fine for Amazon Linux 2:

```
sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo http://fishshell.com/files/linux/RedHat_RHEL-6/fish.release:2.repo
```

After that you can install it normally.

```
sudo yum -y install fish
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and provide a brief explanation. Code only answers are frowned upon on stack overflow and so I bumped into it on a low-quality post queueI'll let it go but another reviewer might choose to delete it otherwise in the futuure.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on release:

```
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
```

add repo

```
sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo http://fishshell.com/files/linux/RedHat_RHEL-6/fish.release:2.repo
```

clean

```
sudo yum clean all
```

install

```
sudo yum -y install fish
```

test

```
    [ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-x-xx] yum.repos.d]$ fish
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
```

Answer (score 0):

For fish 3 see the instructions on the README https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell#building-from-source-all-platforms---makefile-generator